# Usage of the column "ExecutionId" in the table "[dbo].[ExecutionLog2]"

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Can any one of you please help me by providing more details of the column "ExecutionId" in the table "[dbo].[ExecutionLog2]". I thought for each and every report execution from report server it 
will create one execution id. However I find one "ExecutionId" has repeated 70 times (Same "ExecutionId") in one of the report server database. So wondering what does it mean/usage of the column "ExecutionId" in the table "[dbo].[ExecutionLog2]"

Comment: Check this article..  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2722/sql-server-report-server-2008-r2-execution-log-reports/

Answer (score 1):

The internal identifier associated with a request. Requests on the same user sessions share the same execution id.

[Sql Server Reporting Services Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view#a-namebkmkexecutionlog3a-log-fields-executionlog3)

Answer (score 0):

The ExecutionID field appears to be related to (one or more) executions of a **specific report**.  As long as you are running the same report, the ExecutionId appears not to change, regardless of how many times the report is run, even if the report is run with different parameters and even if the output format is changed (e.g. render on screen, pdf, csv etc.)

As soon as you navigate away from the report, a new ExecutionId will be generated for the next report execution.